# Last day of DatePickerDialog is not selectable after setting max date

Tags: android

After using setMaxDate to limit the number of days selectable on the DatePickerDialog, the last day is not greyed out but is not selectable. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
private void showDatePickerDialog() {
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
    DateTime tomorrow = dateTime.plusDays(1);
    int year = tomorrow.getYear();
    int month = tomorrow.getMonthOfYear() -1; // zero based months
    int day = tomorrow.getDayOfMonth();

    DateTime thirtyDaysInFuture = dateTime.plusDays(30);

    long tomorrowMilliseconds = tomorrow.getMillis();
    long futureMilliseconds = thirtyDaysInFuture.getMillis();


    Log.d(TAG, "YEAR: " + year + ", MONTH: " + month + ", DAY: " + day);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            Log.d(TAG, i + ", " + i1 + ", " + i2);

        }
    }, year, month, day);

    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(tomorrowMilliseconds);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(futureMilliseconds);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Just curious if you ever found the solution to this? I am having the same problem. I can't select the last selectable date (even though it shows selectable). The weird thing is, it works just fine on a virtual device, but not my actual phone.

Comment: This seems to be specific to certain versions of Android. In my case, a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 running Android 5.1.1. From what I've read, this may apply to all lollipop devices.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by setting the hour, minute and second of the max date to 23, 59 and 59 respectively.

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, 
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                // Add your code here
            }
        }, year, month, day);

Calendar maxDate = Calendar.getInstance();
maxDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
maxDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
maxDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDate.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and I found an answer. Try to use this code:

> First you should reset current date, it's hours, minutes and seconds

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 14); //I set max date +2 weeks
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 59);

        dlgDate.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Hope I help you